# visual studio 13 ssrs expression builder seems disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

Can anyone tell me why the expression builder seems disabled and how to fix it?

[image: click here to see image!]

Comment: Did you install it?  The default visual studio installs are missing a lot of features.  You can re-run the installer to add missing features.

Comment: No I did not. The company i work for did. I have been using VS for almost 2 years now with no issues, then today during our "sprint" week, issues lol.

Comment: Same thing happening to me only I can't even bring up the dialog.  The button to bring it up is disabled.

Comment: I had to reinstall VS to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling VS seemed to be the only fix.